# Renaming modules in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I picked the wrong name of a specific module which I imported to the Gradle project in Android Studio.

[image]

In this face I want to rename module `Facebook1` to `Facebook`.

Is this possible in Gradle project and how to do it?

Comment: 10 months later, and renaming a module is still not working... I spend more time on IDE's flaws than on my own apps. Shame on Google.

Comment: I renamed my root-module by just closing my project. Renaming  the root directory/ module and after that the *.iml file in the root directory. Restarted after that and it worked.

Answer (score 142):

### Android Studio >= 1.4.1

1. Right click the module -> Refactor -> Rename.
2. Enter the new name of the module, click OK.

### Older versions of Android Studio

The following worked for me, tested in Android Studio (AS) 1.1 & 1.0.2, directly after importing a project.

Under the 'Android' tree view (ATV),

1. Right click the module name: `app`, Refactor -> Rename (to `myApp`, click ok)
2. Open `settings.gradle`
3. Change `':app'` to `':myApp'`, and save
4. You will be prompted to '**Sync Now**', do it (the prompt is a blue link above the file)

   (*Your project will disappear from ATV, but don't worry, just exit AS*)
5. From a file manager (outside of Android Studio), open your project root directory, and rename the folder `app` to `myApp`
6. Re-open your project in AS, and you will see your module and Gradle scripts re-appear under ATV! :)

Congratulations - your module has now been renamed!  (whew, time for some tea)

Comment: Not sure if this is totally proper way, but it really works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I wrote this, and perhaps why you are here, is because currently _there is no proper way_.  @Scadge

Comment: Thanks for solution. Its a shame on Google that attempt to rename app module through Android Studio's UI ruins the project.

Comment: @T.Coutlakis simple question: step 5 must be done directly in the file system? I've done the same that you did but ommited that step, perhaps it's mandatory? - I was in Project View and in the "Select Refactoring" dialog I chose "Rename module", ending up with a module name different from the directory name. After some changes in the project, the refactoring did not persist :/

Comment: @Jose_GD yes, I did it in the filesystem (use Windows Explorer/Finder/Terminal etc), outside of Android Studio.

Comment: I can confirm with @Jose_GD
Renaming the module from AS, causes the submodule to be renamed in AS, BUT in the file system all that happened is that the a new folder with the new name is created and the appropriate iml file was inserted into the newly created folder and the old module's folder remains untouched except for the iml being deleted.
**To fix this,** I shifted all the contents of the older folder to the new folder then deleted the old folder. Then I also had to delete `include 'app'`, do a gradle sync then add it again and do another gradle sync!
So do not rename the module from AS!

Comment: @T.Coutlakis Please update your answer to specify renaming of the submodule **using a file explorer** and not AS. To save people a lot of effort. :)

Comment: -1 I'm doing it on a freshly created project, step 4 never happens, when I sync manually Gradle shows an error about missing module app, then I close the project, I do the renaming on the file system, I reopen the project, and nothing shows on the ATV. Congratulations, you have lost one hour because of outdated StackOverflow answers and sloppy Google developers who are unable to put a fricking rename operation in a IDE.

Comment: After reopening the project after folder rename, I had to force gradle sync again, but after that it worked.  This functionality really has to be in the IDE.

Comment: Came back to this answer and found that I already have an easier way which I didn't know. Thanks for keeping your answer up to date.

Comment: im using 1.2.1.1 and the older version steps worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it doesn't specify the explorer view required (**project** not android), the answer by @henrychuang below is correct

Answer (score 16):

You can do it manually, with or without changing the folder structure (consider not change it for a minor impact on version controlling)

**Changing folder name accordingly**

1- open `settings.gradle` and change the name of your module (exemple from `':facebook1'` to `':facebook'`)

2- change the folder name accordingly (from `xxx/facebook1` to `xxx/facebook`)

3- If other Modules have dependencies on it: open the corresponding `build.gradle` and change dependency (from `compile project(':facebook1')` to `compile project(':facebook')` )

**Without changing folder name**

1- open `settings.gradle` and change the name of your module (exemple from `':facebook1'` to `':facebook'`)

2- add a new line on "settings.gradle":

```
project(':facebook').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '/facebook1')
```

3- If other Modules have dependencies on it: open the corresponding `build.gradle` and change dependency (from `compile project(':facebook1')` to `compile project(':facebook')` )

Answer (score 14):

In the project view on the left in Android Studio,

1. right click on the module whose name you want to change
2. select 'refactor' -> 'rename'
3. choose the rename module option
4. follow step 1 - 2 and then rename the directory too

Comment: This does not rename the reference in the `Project Structure`. I can still see the old name. So this will work only if Gradle does not allow renaming.

Comment: @sandalone you need to update your settings.gradle file with the new module name also

Comment: directory name is also updated when we rename module option. I just tried.

Comment: @AdnanAli, that means this answer is not based on experience or something but is out of air ))

Answer (score 12):

Android Studio 1.3.2,

1. switch Project view on the left in Android Studio

2. right click module which want to change -> Refactor -> Rename

3. do both "Rename directory" and "Rename module"

4. open settings.gradle, change module name

5. Build -> Clean Project

Comment: This IS the correct answer for AS 1.3.2. If AS throws an IOException, make sure all files in your project are not open in an editor or file explorer.

Comment: This is correct as of Android Studio 2.1.1 as well, although renaming just the module will also rename the directory.

Comment: This is still the correct answer as of android studio 2.2, if you try to refactor within the android view it will **not** rename the directory automatically and causes the missing module error

Answer (score 4):

> As of Android Studio 3.4.1

**Rename module**

1. In Project window, right-click module and select `Refactor > Rename`
2. Choose `Rename module` and press `OK`
3. Enter new module name and press `OK`
4. **Important** `settings.gradle` is updated automatically. However, you must manually update any `build.gradle` dependencies to reflect new module name:

```
dependencies {
    // manually update this after renaming the module
    implementation project(':newmodulename')
}
```

**Rename package to reflect new module name**

1. In Project window, right-click desired package and select `Refactor > Rename`
2. If there are other src sets with same package name (`test` or `androidTest`), a dialog will ask if you want to rename them as well. If so, select `Rename package`
3. Enter new package name and press `Refactor`
4. Select `Do Refactor` in the Refactoring Preview

> Tip: Select `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` to fix any unresolved resource references caused by renaming a module.

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidStudio 2.2.2 renaming the module alone via refactor/rename worked for me. (32-bit linux Mint)

The rename dialog presents two options: "directory" or "module" (radio buttons so mutually exclusive, at least in one pass).  I wasn't sure which to pick so I ended here looking for an answer.  One answer said "do both" as two steps, another answer said "do module, then directory" as two steps.  So I chose "module" first.  To my surprise that was all that was needed, both module and directory were changed. settings.gradle was updated by the refactor/rename in the one step as well.

"gradle synce" and "clean build" were also triggered.  Upon build to my tablet, no complaint about the name change.

just adding this answer in case someone else with 2.2.2 or later is unsure which to pick.  Also to re-iterate what others have said, back up your project first.

Comment: I followed this, but then had to edit 1) the .iml file for the module 2) the .iml file for the project 3) the module build.gradle 4) the project settings.gradle

Comment: ... and 5) accept 'remove module [Old Module Name] from project' 6) Invalidate Cache And Restart twice.   So YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

1. Close Project and rename module folder `oldName` to `newName` then open Project and  change module name `include ':oldName'` to `include ':newName'` in `settings.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Premise: I do NOT use the refactor function of Android Studio to rename the module

These are the steps I perform:

1. Rename the folder of the module (directly in the file system)
2. Modify the setting.gradle file accordingly (directly in the file system)
3. Open the project in Android Studio

That's all.

Comment: Your 3rd step is the same as your 2nd step. Furthermore, this does not work, even in AS 1.2.2, so who knows what you really did to make the rename work.

Comment: You are right 2nd and 3rd steps are equal (edited). The version is 1.2.1.1 (mac os) not the 1.2.2.

Answer (score -2):

Different people seem to have success with different methods, but when I wanted to rename my project from:

com.example.myname.projectname

to

com.company.projectname

I tried everything and the only way I got it to work in the end was:

1) Exit Android Studio
2) back everything up! (find your project folder and make a copy of it)
3) Find and replace all instances of com.example.myname.projectname with com.company.projectname

Note that there are five places (actually it probably depends on your project, I had five) where you need to rename folders, as it creates subfolders called com\example\myname\projectname:

project\app\src\main\java
project\app\src\androidTest\java
project\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\
project\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\test\
project\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\

Also, in project.idea\ there is a file called workspace.xml - in that file you'll need to find the text com\example\myname\projectname

Otherwise, do a search through the project directory to find "com.example.myname.projectname" and replace with "com.company.projectname"

4) Open Android Studio again.  if the initial project directory name is the same (possibly if the project name itself is the same?) it will reopen if you had it open last time, otherwise you should be able to open as normal.

5) Go to File - Project Structure (CONTROL+ALT+SHIFT+S).
6) Under "Flavors", change the application ID to the new name.
7) Excit Android Studio and restart it.
8) Now you should be able to build your project.
9) Go have a drink, that was a lot more effort than it should have been!

One really important note, you can only have ASCII letters in your package name (you may be able to have numbers, but not as the first character).  Java itself allows numbers to start a package name, but Android does not: [Package names in Android studio when dev name starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666297/package-names-in-android-studio-when-dev-name-starts-with-a-number/28666328#28666328) I was trying to rename

My workaround (and from a look around the apps on my phone it seems to be what others are doing) is if you wanted a number at the start of either your company name or app name, write the word - instead of com.123company.55project perhaps use com.onetwothreecompany.fiftyfiveproject

Comment: The question here refers to modules, not package names. They are not the same

Comment: Good point, my mistake!  I came across this thread when I was solving the issue of renaming my project and thought I'd be helpful and post the solution I worked out.  Obviously I didn't read it properly, sorry!