# How do I fix Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main'?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Can anyone help me fix this problem? Everything seems fine. My xml and java looks normal but I can't seem to find what is wrong with the error. I already tried invalidating my cache and cleaning the project but the error is still there. Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

My Problem:
Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main'

[image]

MainActivity

```
package com.example.machineproblem2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_msg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/lbl_msg">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_send"
        android:onClick="doNextActivity"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/msg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to restart your android studio.

Comment: It seems your project has error in build, check other errors, if no error found you should to import your R (resource file) in your java code,

Comment: Import Resources, `import YOUR_PACKAG_NAME.R`

Comment: i agree with @LakhwinderSingh, you need to import resources `R`

Comment: try to update android studio if it is not update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested fixes were not really working so what I did was.

1. Copied the contents of activity_main
2. Delete the activity_main
3. Create a new layout of the same name
4. Pasted the copied contents of the previous xml file to the new layout.

It is a mystery why it did not detect the previous activity_main but this fix seemed to work

Answer (score 3):

1 - try to Clean then Rebuild project (Build > Clean Project / Rebuild Project)

2 - if (1) not work with you click : File > Invalidate Caches / Restart',
    and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.

Comment: Does not work. I already said it in my post above

Comment: So i think you need to reset Android studio settings, delete Android Studio folder :

C:\Users\USER_NAME\.AndroidStudioX.X

Answer (score 1):

add

```
import com.example.machineproblem2.R
```

I don't see it in your imports, so Activity cannot resolve activity_main.xml because it doesn't understand what is R mean.

Another workaround:

try to rename your package from com.example.machineproblem2 to com.example.machineproblem. 
It is possible what you break the rule of individual package naming (see: [Package names in Android studio when dev name starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666297/package-names-in-android-studio-when-dev-name-starts-with-a-number/28666328))

Comment: I already did that but still does not work. I retyped setContentView(R.layout.); but the autocomplete does not show the activity_main xml 

the only thing that showed up is support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item and class

Comment: Please send your projects' file structure (in screenshot "Android" mode used, choose "Project").

Comment: I add another workaround in answer. Please check. Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Does R.layout have access to the other xml layouts? (activity_second & layout_toast)? That was at least you'll know if its an issue with that layout specifically or with the project in general. If the others work then consider copy-pasting the layout and see if you can reference the new one then.

Comment: Nope. NO access. It only shows support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item and class

Comment: I would create a new project and check if it works there, just to rule out it been a problem with the installation. Also, you could make a new java class and see if you can reference the layouts from there.  Additionally you could try deleting all the imports at the top, I dont think most of them are used and maybe one of them is screwing your references for some strange reason.

Comment: Well I am going to need to use them on my future codes. I usually lay down all my imports first when I start project

Comment: I understand, I'm just trying eliminate code temporally to discard possibilities