# Android project name package changed

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, package-name, google-play-services

I used android Studio 1.5. 
In my android project, I changed the name package and then this error is appear

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name

Can you help me?

Comment: which google services are you using?

Comment: Well I fixed the problem: I changed the package name in google-services.json but nox the problem is The google maps does not appear ..

Comment: Did you changed it via "Refactor" - "Rename"?

Comment: Yes I changes it via Refactor.

Comment: In fact, the change of the package name  does not modified in all the files, so I must verify all the files in the project. Besides, I changed the package name in https://console.developers.google.com/ to appear the google maps properly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, today I faced the samg issue.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936812/renaming-modules-in-android-studio/27892670#27892670) answer helped me.
Hope you can reverse your changes and do refactoring.

***Did it help you?***