# Generate Signed APK: Project Name

Tags: android, android-studio

While trying to publish my first Android App to Google play I was about to generate the signed APK when I noticed the module name is "app".

From the instructions I followed, I've understood this should be the actual name of my app? (my app's name is not "app", the package name does mention my app name.)

From the androidManifest.xml I have made the label name "blank", I removed my app name from there because I don't want the app name to appear in the action bar/tool bar. I've used my own special font for that.

Question 1:I am wondering what would happen if I just continue with "app" in module name, will my app be published with the name "app"?  Do I have to change it to reflect my app's actual name? If yes then see question #2 below.

Question 2. If required to change then how I can change that folder name from "app" to my actual app name? Assuming changing this will then reflect the correct name in the module while generating the signed APK? The first folder in the top left corner under project is called "app"??

Comment: The first folder being called "app" is normal. At what point is your module named "app"? Your package name is the most important. And when you publish it, you specify a name for the play store. I think what you are seeing is ignorable. Should there be somewhere, packagename etc called "app" you can use the refactor tool. Right click, refactor, change name.

Comment: Check this out. This will help. You are doing fine. Keep doing.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187080/android-studio-new-project-vs-new-module

Answer (score 1):

Module name does not influence a name that your app is published with. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name) how to do so (you need to change `label` in your manifest). By default, module name influences such internal things as a folder name or an APK file name generated by Android Studio.

Although you don't need to change `app` to match your application name in any way, you may want to give your project's modules some logical names that just make sense. To do so, use Refactor -> Rename feature of Android Studio (available on right click on module name). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936812/renaming-modules-in-android-studio) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes,if not busy "app", you can publish application with name "app".
2. The folder name not depends from application name. 
   You may change application name for whatever you want, but you can't change package name after publishing in Google Play.(example: **com.android.app**)