# I cannot rename a module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have 2 modules:

```
app
library
```

I want to rename "library" to "XName" (for example)

I used the refactor method (Right click -> Refactor -> Rename) it works.

**However,** when I rebuild the project the module gets renamed back to "library".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this post. [Renaming module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936812/renaming-modules-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Vuksa I've tried all of those. The only option is to do it manually, which I am going to do, but I will leave this post to see if anyone can get past this bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste your module inside the library folder and rename it.we cant rename the library folder directly in android.
for more details refer [Create an Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Comment: I know that option and I will do it. But I'm keeping this question so if anyone finds a workaround, they can post it here.